# ¿El uso de PRIMARY KEY y FOREIGN KEY puede optimizar la ejecución de mis consultas? SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimización, rendimiento

Me gustaria primero plantearles mi situacion, estoy creando un SP el cual me muestre un informe de los cursos realizados en una empresa, donde me comparten un SP(Linked Server) donde me muestra esa información. Entonces en mi SP lo que hago es ejecutar ese SP de otro servidor y unirlo a mi tabla de empleados para agregar informacion adicional, para ello creo una tabla temporal para alojar los resultados del SP del otro servidor, teniendo en cuenta que para ejecutar este SP se necesitan de parametros como:

- Un listado de nominas para buscar a los empleados
- Rango de fechas para buscar si realizaron algun curso en ese periodo

Entonces teniendo en cuenta esto realice mi SP pero este me tarda varios minutos en ejecutar(2-5min). He estado investigando que puedo hacer para optimizar la ejecucion y en muchos casos es utilizar **"Indices"** pero realmente no se como utilizarlos, En otros caso vi que tiene que ver con las tablas temporales, y tambien vi que en algunos casos se mencionaba usar lo de llave primaria y secundaria en la tabla temporal pero ¿Esto me ayudara? ¿Que puedo hacer para mejorar el rendimiento?

**NOTA: Tambien ya intente reemplazar la tabla temporal por una normal**

Aqui les dejo mi SP de lo que hice:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE TR_RepEquiposRodantes
@UserID varchar(100),
@Report varchar(100),
@Setting varchar(100),
@dummy varchar(max) NULL,
@certificacion varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN   
            SET NOCOUNT ON;

            DECLARE @res varchar(max)= NULL                 
            DECLARE @t TABLE (resultado VARCHAR(MAX))

            DECLARE @Fechainicio date
            set @Fechainicio = '01-01-1989'
            DECLARE @Fechafin date
            set @Fechafin = GETDATE()           
                    
            declare @curso varchar(max) 
            set @curso = (select Val from tblMatrices where ID=3656)
            declare  @Idmatriz varchar(max) 
            set @Idmatriz = (select id from tblMatrices where ID=3656)

            DECLARE @Incp varchar(max)              
            select @Incp = stuff( (select ',' + cast(t.WorkdayID as varchar(max))
            from tblIncapacidades t
            for xml path ('')
            ), 1, 1, ''
            );      

            /*  Tabla temporal para almacenar los resultado de la lista de cursos   */
            CREATE TABLE #udvM12953_CoursesList (
            cur_clave varchar(max),
            cur_nombre varchar(max),
            fecha_valido_desde date,
            duracion int,
            RevisionID int,
            RevisionName varchar(100),
            tipo_empleado varchar(50)
            )
        
            /*  GUARDAR DUMMY Y REEMPLAZAR  */      
            BEGIN                       
                INSERT INTO @t 
                exec spu_SetUserSetting @UserID, @Report, @Setting, @dummy          
                SELECT @res=resultado FROM @t

            /*  MATRIZ PLASTICOS    */
            IF @Idmatriz = '3656'               
                BEGIN           
                
                exec TR_EquiposRodantesNA @dummy, @certificacion

                INSERT INTO Temp_Rep065
                exec [NameLinkedServer].[Database].[dbo].[udpM12953_Reporte065]
                @DateStart = @Fechainicio,--@dStart,
                @DateEnd = @Fechafin,--@dEnd,
                @cur_clave_str = @curso,
                @emp_clave_str = @dummy /*  DUMMY MECHANICALS IDL   */
                
                /*  Lista de Cursos */
                INSERT INTO #udvM12953_CoursesList
                exec [NameLinkedServer].[Database].[dbo].[udvM12953_CoursesList]                            

                ;WITH cteEquiposRodantes AS(
                    select h.workDayId,h.EmployeeName,h.JobPosition,h.Manager1,h.Manager2,                  
                    t.clave,
                    t.nombre_curso,
                    t.calif, 
                    case when(t.fecha_examen IS NULL)   
                    then Convert(nvarchar,GETDATE(),23)
                    else t.fecha_examen
                    end as fecha_examen,
                    CASE
                    WHEN ISDATE(es_fecha_inicio) = 1 THEN CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, es_fecha_inicio), 120)
                    ELSE es_fecha_inicio
                    END AS es_fecha_inicio,
                    c.fecha_valido_desde,H.inactiveDate,
                    r.cer_clave,r.cer_nombre,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY h.workDayId, t.clave 
                                        ORDER BY
                                        CASE WHEN r.cer_nombre = @certificacion THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, 
                                        t.fecha_examen DESC, 
                                        t.calif ASC
                    ) as rowNumber
                    FROM TableHeadCount h 
                    LEFT JOIN Temp_Rep065 t ON h.workDayId = t.emp_clave
                    LEFT JOIN Temp_Rep277 r ON h.workDayId = r.emp_clave                    
                    LEFT JOIN #udvM12953_CoursesList c ON t.clave = c.cur_clave
                    WHERE h.workDayId IN (SELECT value 
                        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@dummy, ','))
                    AND h.inactiveDate IS NULL
                ), cteEquiposRodantes_Two as(
                    select workDayId,EmployeeName,JobPosition,Manager1,Manager2,clave,nombre_curso,
                    case when(calif = 'C')
                    then '100'
                      when(calif = 'N/A')
                    then '200'
                    else calif
                    end as calif,
                    cer_clave,cer_nombre,
                    fecha_examen,fecha_valido_desde
                    from cteEquiposRodantes 
                    where rowNumber = 1                 
                ), cteEquiposRodantes_Three as (
                    select workDayId, EmployeeName,JobPosition,Manager1,Manager2,clave,nombre_curso,
                    case when ((calif >= 80 and calif < 200) and fecha_examen >= fecha_valido_desde)
                    then '1'
                      when(calif=200)
                    then '2'
                    else '0'
                    end as calif,
                    cer_clave,cer_nombre,
                    fecha_examen,fecha_valido_desde
                    from cteEquiposRodantes_Two
                    where workDayId NOT IN (SELECT value -- NO INCLUYE A LAS PERSONAS DE INCAPACIDADES
                        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Incp, ','))
                    AND cer_nombre = @certificacion
                )
                select * from cteEquiposRodantes_Three

                END
            END
END
GO
```

Comment: Los índices (ovidate de PK y FK) si son los adecuados para un determinada consulta sin duda mejoran la performance, justamente esa es la idea de un índice.  Ahora, antes de pensar de que manera solucionar el problema, deberías investigar cual es el problema, que demore mucho tiempo es un síntoma pero no el problema.  Busca dónde realmente estaría el "cuello de botella", ¿está en la consulta remota? ¿está en el volumen de datos que viajan de un servidor a otro? ¿Está en las consultas de tu propio Sp?

Comment: Por mi experiencia, el uso de linked servers suele ser un generador constante de "cuellos de botella", ejecuta el sp en el servidor de origen ¿Cuánto demora? has la inserción llamando al Sp por linked server ¿Cuánto demora?

Comment: Asi es, esta en la consulta del SP. Realice la consulta solo con el SP del otro servidor y realmente no tarda mucho solo unos cuantos segundos, supongo yo que es por todos los procesos que realizo al insertar los datos obtenidos en mi SP y los joins con las demas tablas para sacar mi consulta... ¿HAY ALGUNA MANERA DE VER QUE PROCESO DE MI SP ES DONDE SE TARDA EN EJECUTAR?

Comment: Revisa el query plan, eso te da una pauta de que parte del SP se lleva el mayor porcentaje de recursos, sino estás familiarizado con esto, simplemente ejecuta paso a paso y ubica que parte de todo el código es la que demora mas